# Trying to return sum of the numbers in a string. If string is "99Hello1" output is 100, if it is "9hello9" answer is 18. Struck with clueless error

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function NumberSearch(str) {
    var arr = str.split("");
    var sum = 0;
    var twoDigit = [];
    var two;
    var res = [];
    var arrFormat = preProcess(arr);
    console.log(arrFormat);
    //this function returns an array that has all numbers from the string
    function preProcess(ele) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
            if (typeof ele[i] === 'number' && typeof ele[i + 1] === 'number') {
                twoDigit.push(ele[i], ele[i + 1]);
                two = twoDigit.join("");
                res.push(two);
            } else {
                if (typeof ele[i] === 'number' && typeof ele[i + 1] !== 
            'number') {
                    res.push(ele[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    for (var k = 0; k < arrFormat.length; k++) {
        sum = sum + arrFormat[k];
    }
    return sum;
}

console.log(NumberSearch("99Hello1"));
```

I am trying to solve the problem by first looping through the string and collecting all numbers and then summing up.

Comment: you have strings after splitting. and your check does not work like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for matching numbers and reduce the gotten array.

```js
function sum(string) {
    return (string.match(/\d+/g) || []).reduce(function (a, b) { return a + +b; }, 0)
}

console.log(['99hello1', '9hello9'].map(sum));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also perform this job with a single reducing stage.

```js
var s = Array.prototype.reduce.call("99Hello9", (r,c) => isNaN(+c) ? r : +c+r, 0);
console.log(s);
```